# Divide long string into x character long lines or shorter but don't break words

Tags: python, string, newline, words

```
import textwrap
print(textwrap.fill(text, 50))
```

I found this function, but it breaks words. I also found [Divide long string into 60 character long lines but don't break words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678051/divide-long-string-into-60-character-long-lines-but-dont-break-words), but it uses C# not Python.

Comment: Well if the standard library method doesn't work for you, have you considered writing your own?

Comment: I tried but it's shameful

Answer (score 1):

Textwrap will do that if you ask it to:

```
import textwrap
print(textwrap.fill(text, 50, break_long_words=False)
```

See the [textwrap module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) for details on `break_long_words` and other optional parameters.